# React Router: custom browser router getUserConfirmation dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got custom `BrowserRouter` component because I need access to history instance out of React Component, so I've created it this way:

**OwnBrowserRouter.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default class OwnBrowserRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  history = history
}
```

Then I'm using this `OwnBrowserRouter` component in my app and passing `getUserConfirmation` component with custom modal:

**App.js**

```
<OwnBrowserRouter getUserConfirmation={getUserConfirmation}> ... </>
```

**getUserConfirmation.js**

```
const getUserConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
  const modal = document.createElement("div")
  document.body.appendChild(modal)

  const withCleanup = answer => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(modal)
    document.body.removeChild(modal)
    callback(answer)
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <ConfirmModal
      open={true}
      type={MODAL.TYPE.CANCEL}
      handleClose={() => withCleanup(false)}
      handleConfirm={() => withCleanup(true)}
      title="Are you sure?"
      text={message}
    />,
    modal
  )
}

export default getUserConfirmation
```

Then I'm (of course) rendering `<Prompt>` component somewhere... Main problem is that it works with origin `BrowserRouter` imported from `react-router-dom` but whenever I switch to `OwnBrowserRouter`, it starts to display ugly browser dialog (not my custom styled modal).

Comment: No need to create custom browser router, You can use this.props.history to access the history from BrowserRouter

Comment: @Nisfan as I wrote I need to access to history outside react components and there you don't have props.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in answer, `getUserConfirmation` is actually a history API, so the solution is

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({ getUserConfirmation })
```

Comment: this is awesome for those using low lever Router from 'react-router' which doesnt accept `getUserConfirmation` as a prop. Thanks, @ketysek